# Numpy: Size of a 2D array matrix?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

How do my 2 statements bellow differ in internal mechanism, while they are however giving the same output?

```py
x = np.array([[**1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8**], [**4,  5, 6, 8, 9, 5**]])

np.size(x)

x.size
```

Both are correct outputs as the size of the array is 12.

Comment: They are actually the same method. `x.size` is converted to `np.size(x)` internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally `np.size(x)` calls `x.size` when axis is not specified sp in this case the result is the same.

```
if axis is None:
    try:
        return a.size
    except AttributeError:
        return asarray(a).size
```

However, if you specify the `axis`, then the result would be different.

```
>>> a=np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
>>> a.shape
(4, 4)
>>> np.size(a,axis=1)
4
>>> a.size
16
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.size` accepts parameter axis; `x.size` always returns the total number of elements:

```
def size(a, axis=None):
    """
    Return the number of elements along a given axis.

    Parameters
    ----------
    a : array_like
        Input data.
    axis : int, optional
        Axis along which the elements are counted.  By default, give
        the total number of elements.

    Returns
    -------
    element_count : int
        Number of elements along the specified axis.

    See Also
    --------
    shape : dimensions of array
    ndarray.shape : dimensions of array
    ndarray.size : number of elements in array

    Examples
    --------
    >>> a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
    >>> np.size(a)
    6
    >>> np.size(a,1)
    3
    >>> np.size(a,0)
    2

    """
    if axis is None:
        try:
            return a.size
        except AttributeError:
            return asarray(a).size
    else:
        try:
            return a.shape[axis]
        except AttributeError:
            return asarray(a).shape[axis]
```